# Is it possible to develop for Android 4.4W with Android 5.0 SDK installed?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I recently updated Eclipse to Android 5.0 (bad idea) and the android-support-v7-appcompat library now will not compile unless the target is set to android-21. The app I was working on was running using API 20, but now will not run unless the AndroidManifest's targetSdkVersion is set to 21. This changes the look of some assets. Is it possible with the new appcompat to still deploy to version 20, or, if that's not possible, can I downgrade everything back to the previous API version? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to downgrade to SDK 20:

1. Re-download appcompat version 20: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r20.zip
2. Delete the appcompat project from your app's workspace
3. Import the appcompat version 20
4. Set the Build Target for android-support-v7-appcompat to Android 4.4W.2 (in Project->Properties->Android)
5. In order to get the app to run, change its AndroidManifest's targetSdkVersion to 20
6. For the app, in Project->Properties->Android, set the Build Target to Android 4.4W.2, re-add the appcompat library in the Library window. Also, Under Java Build Path, re-add android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar under Libraries and uncheck those two jar files under Order and Export (this one killed me for a while).
7. Clean and build.
8. Pray to God it works.

Comment: You're my hero! v21 screwed me over - it removed my App Icon and changed the colour of the text. This fixed it